# JTable Insert Query

Tags: java, sql, insert, jtable

Im new to JFrame Jtable. Been trying to do a insert query but im getting "column not allowed here" error.

```
private void AddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try{
        theQuery("INSERT INTO CONFERENCE(CONFERENCEID,NAME,YEAR,STARTDATE,ENDDATE,COUNTRY,CITY,VENUE,EMAIL)"
          +"values('"+cid.getText()+"','"+cname.getText()+"','"+cyear.getYear()+"','"
          +csd.getDate()+"','"+ced.getDate()+"','"+country.getText()+"','"+city.getText()
          +"','"+venue.getText()+"',"+email.getText()+")");
    } catch(Exception ex){}
}   

     public void theQuery(String query){
  Connection con = null; Statement st = null;
  try{ con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@example:123", "123", "student"); 
  st = con.createStatement(); 
  st.executeUpdate(query); 
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Query Executed"); }
  catch(Exception ex){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage()); } }
```

Comment: can we see the method theQuery() ? Also i would recmmend  you to use prepared statements instead of raw queries.

Comment: yup added the method thequery

Comment: try adding parantheses here ",' "+email.getText()+" ')"

Comment: email invalid unidentifer

Comment: Sorry, try adding quotes just like in other fields you have written in the query. Only the email thing is missing the single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make your Connection System like this for the begining.

```
 public void theQuery()
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourBDD";
    String sqlLogin = "login";
    String sqlPassword = "password";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, sqlLogin, sqlPassword);
    String query = " insert into CONFERENCE(CONFERENCEID, NAME, YEAR, COUNTRY, CITY, VENUE, EMAIL) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = cnx.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStmt.setString(1, cid.getText());
    preparedStmt.setString(2, cname.getText());
    preparedStmt.setString(3, cyear.getYear());
    preparedStmt.setString(4, csd.getDate());
    preparedStmt.setString(5, ced.getDate());
    preparedStmt.setString(6, country.getText());
    preparedStmt.setString(7, city.getText();
    ...
    preparedStmt.execute();
    conn.close(); 
}
```